# adb.exe not found after installing Android Studio

Tags: android, adb

I installed Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and also created virtual device. I am trying to install one app (APK file) through command line but I could not find `adb.exe` file on my machine. Please help where should I look for `adb.exe` file on the machine.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The adb.exe file will be located at your Android SDK folder, inside platform-tools

```
...\android-sdk-path\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

The default location where Android SDK is installed is:

```
C:\Users\<insert username here>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
```

So adb will be located at:

```
C:\Users\<insert username here>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

---

To access it on a command line, open cmd.exe and type:

```
cd C:\Users\<insert username here>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\
```

and then your normal command

```
adb <insert parameters here>
```

Comment: Thanks PANAYIOTIS !! I got it. I was looking under program files.

Comment: or u can do this: add %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools to your PATH environment variables, then you can simply call adb anywhere you want.

Comment: I can't find and folder named "android" in AppData\Local folder. Hidden folders are also visible.

Comment: @SahilPatel Did you start Android Studio? Cause only then will the SDK be downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 3):

May be adb.exe file is missing form your computer. Try deleting platform-tools folder and re-download it from SDKManager.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS El Capitan has it located at /Users/[username]/depot_tools/src/chrome/browser/devtools/device

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adb.exe got deleted after Android Studio update. I copied all the contents under platform-tools to another directory, deleted all the contents under platform-tools and installed platform-tools from Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in Android Studio, under System Settings > Andorid SDK > tab called SDK Tools, you have checked this option:

[image]