# How can I run my ionic app on a physical device (Wiko phone) on Windows?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, window

I have a project using `ionic framework`, I am working in command line and I am trying to run my app on on a real device phone, a `Wiko Rainbow`.

I have enabled **On-device Developer Options** and I also have enabled **USB debugging** option and the target device is never recognized. I am working on `Windows 7`.

*I have done:* `ionic run android`

*And the result:*

> No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator

Is my device phone phone compatible with ionic or am I missing sommeting ?

I manage to find the solution I had to the environnent variables path:

```
<my pc>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;
<my pc>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
```

Then I update the driver of my device thanks to this link: [Android development driver for Wiko or other phone on Windows 7](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-use-android-adb-driver-installer-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8.html)

A few time later my phone asked me to accept the connexion with my computer and I managed to run my application.

Comment: Does adb on the command line show your device? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list

Comment: when I type: `adb devices` I have `'adb' is not recongnized...`

Comment: Have you installed the Android SDK/Android Studio? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812493/adb-exe-not-found-after-installing-android-studio

Comment: Yes, I manage to setup `adb` in path by adding `tools` and `plateform-tool` in my path environment variable, now I can't detect my `Wiko`, maybe there is something wrong with this phone.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you, I installed the driver and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I update the driver of my device thanks to this link: [Android development driver for Wiko or other phone on Windows 7](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-use-android-adb-driver-installer-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8.html)

A few time later my phone asked me to accept the connexion with my computer and I managed to run my application.