# ADB for Le Eco 2 smartphone

Tags: android, adb

How to and from where to download Android Debuggingd Bridge for Le Eco Smartphone? I checked the Le Eco forum and there were no answers. I have already started the developer mode on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

ADB is included by default in the SDK. You can locate and issue adb commands as stated [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30812540/6690063) But you should enable developer mode **and** install your smartphone's driver in your workstation. Normally in modern smartphones, the driver is installed upon plugging it in via USB. If not, then you should download the appropriate driver depending on your OS.

You can also register adb to your global PATH so you can issue commands right away. After setting this all up, you can then issue the command `adb devices` to see if your phone is detected by adb by showing a serial number in the list of devices.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and found out how to solve it.
Download the universal ADB driver , but windows won't allow you to install this as it is not digitally verified. So, start windows in test mode by disabling digital signatures  and install the driver using device manager. Now open android studio and run any app,(hello world)  le eco should show up in connected devices. This worked provided you turn on usb debugging and set it to media transfer on the phone.
Or you could just intall an exe file in the link which does this for you.
For detailed steps visit this link http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.